# Merge pages from multiple PDF-VT documents via PDFBOX

Tags: optimization, merge, pdfbox

I merge pages from multiple PDF-VT documents via PDFBOX.

But pdfBox creates the output without optimization, therefore the size is huge.

For example, pdfLib handles with the size by "optimize",
is there another way to achieve that via PDFBOX?

I really need your help!!! I have been trying to solve it a long time ago without success.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Please link to sample files. "Linearize" is not about optimizing size, it is about optimizing the sequewence which helps with some readers.

Comment: Hi, i edited the post, thanks... Is there a way to do optimizing via pdbbox? Is not about sample files, it's about any pdf..  I want to reduce the size...

Comment: It would be possible to write such a tool, but usually PDF files are already compressed. So such a work makes only sense if you have sample files of which you know that they have a flaw. But you are alleging that "pdfBox creates the output without optimization". For that you should explain what optimization is missing. (Linearization is not supported by PDFBox)

Comment: Optimization - "PDFLIB can significantly reduce the file size of a PDF document without affecting quality. It achieves this by removing unnecessary or redundant identical objects, such as repeatedly embedded fonts, images, identical ICC color profiles, etc." -  i want to do it with PDFBOX.

Comment: oh. It's not possible out of the box, and I don't have a good idea how to do this quickly. Maybe this product (which is a fork of pdfbox) http://www.pdfsam.org can do it.

Comment: ok, i'll check it.. thanks for your time and your help :)